# Why am I getting an 308 redirect to my origin in cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, vercel

I have a domain in Vercel:
`...-staging.vercel.app`

My Cloudfront looks like this:
`domain name: xxx.cloudfront.net` `alternate domain name: MY-PROD-MAIN.com` `origin:...-staging.vercel.app` (the one in Vercel)

In Route53 I have as record name: `MY-PROD-DOMAIN.com` and in Value/Route traffic to: `xxx.cloudfront.net`

When I make a request to  `MY-PROD-DOMAIN.com` I receive an 308 redirect to my domain in Vercel.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Is it just a http -> https redirect?

Comment: No, the domain is changing from production to the origin in Vercel. Both are https